# Server side rendered imported CSS module not as expected

Tags: reactjs, server-side-rendering, css-modules

Sorry if this issue has been reported before, I've tried to Google a solution and searching the issues here but I can't find something that describes my issue.

I am getting a error in the console from React saying that that the client and server markup do not match and the checksum fails.  This leads to a FOUC.

Consider the following sources:

```
// MyComponent.scss
.myComponent {
   background: black;
}



// MyComponent.js
import styles from './MyComponent.scss';

const MyComponent = () => <div className={styles.myComponent}>Hello</div>;

export default MyComponent;
```

On the client, this works as expected and `styles.myComponent` will be rendered as `MyComponent-myComponent-[hash]` as you might expect.

However, on the server `styles.myComponent` is undefined so the class name is omitted and this is what is causing the error in the console because the DOM structure does not match.  I've logged the styles object and it would appear that on the server there is a `locals` object and this is where I find my rendered component name.  eg

```
styles: {
   locals: {
     myComponent: 'MyComponent-myComponent-[hash]'
   }
}
```

I'm not sure where to start looking as to why the imported css module object appears to be different on the client than on the server.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was bad Webpack configuration.

I'm using the extract-text-plugin to pull out the CSS into separate files.  I have shared modules rules for the client and server bundles respectively.  A created an instance of `ExtractTextPlugin` for the client code and use this instance's `extract` function to wrap the shared modules rule.  In the client config I specified this instance in the plugin chain, but in the server bundle I used `new ExtractTextPlugin()` in the plugin chain and it seems this is what caused the disconnect.

I ended up writing a wrapper function to duplicate the CSS rule for each for of the bundle configurations.